# Change cyril to western characters (both in utf-8) - php

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters, cyrillic

I've got a problem with cyril characters. Our site is in utf-8 and accepts these characters, however our external sources where we pass on characters does not accept them. We are trying to pass on persons names. They have other different charsets (for example iso-8859-1).

Is there any easy way in PHP to convert manually each cyril character into it's equivalent western character first while in utf-8 to avoid the non-proper conversion? If using the conversion methods directly it all gets into question marks.

Comment: Have you tried to find a solution?  If all you want to do is map cyrilic characters onto western ones, it shouldn't be more difficult than str_replace

Comment: Cyril sounds like a Western character already, heh heh `:-)`

Comment: There is a huge number of ways to map Cyrillic letters to Latin letters. The biggest problem is to decide the most adequate way for a particular context and define it exactly; the implementation is then fairly trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which resolved my problem. The function below converts each character from Cyrillic to it's equivalent Western characters. The names get quite accurately converted using this function.

When characters where replace I could use the utf8_decode() to convert it to iso-8859-1.

```
function do_translit($st) {
    $replacement = array(
        "й"=>"i","ц"=>"c","у"=>"u","к"=>"k","е"=>"e","н"=>"n",
        "г"=>"g","ш"=>"sh","щ"=>"sh","з"=>"z","х"=>"x","ъ"=>"\'",
        "ф"=>"f","ы"=>"i","в"=>"v","а"=>"a","п"=>"p","р"=>"r",
        "о"=>"o","л"=>"l","д"=>"d","ж"=>"zh","э"=>"ie","ё"=>"e",
        "я"=>"ya","ч"=>"ch","с"=>"c","м"=>"m","и"=>"i","т"=>"t",
        "ь"=>"\'","б"=>"b","ю"=>"yu",
        "Й"=>"I","Ц"=>"C","У"=>"U","К"=>"K","Е"=>"E","Н"=>"N",
        "Г"=>"G","Ш"=>"SH","Щ"=>"SH","З"=>"Z","Х"=>"X","Ъ"=>"\'",
        "Ф"=>"F","Ы"=>"I","В"=>"V","А"=>"A","П"=>"P","Р"=>"R",
        "О"=>"O","Л"=>"L","Д"=>"D","Ж"=>"ZH","Э"=>"IE","Ё"=>"E",
        "Я"=>"YA","Ч"=>"CH","С"=>"C","М"=>"M","И"=>"I","Т"=>"T",
        "Ь"=>"\'","Б"=>"B","Ю"=>"YU",
    );

    foreach($replacement as $i=>$u) {
        $st = mb_eregi_replace($i,$u,$st);
    }
    return $st;
    }
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-eregi-replace.php